# Allocating AVPlayer causes frames to drop

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avfoundation

I have a UICollectionViewController that autoplays video in its cells (similar to the Vine App). I'm finding that frames drop when scrolling, and I've isolated it to allocating the AVPlayer object in each cell. It doesn't matter if it's done on a background thread or on the main one. Are there any ways of working around this?